# Eclipse and J2ME emulator customization

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, midp

I am new to Eclipse. I had successfully integrated j2me plugin and able to run the j2me application in emulator. But as in Netbeans we have emulator customization facility like we can add icon in our application or change manifest file or like change emulator or update midlet.

How can I do all this customization in eclipse?

Comment: you want to add icon to application ??? running application in both netbeans and eclipse is little bit different. explain your problem in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.My problem is I want to customize the emulator and midlet property then how can i do that??

Comment: you will find ProjectName.jad file in your project, just double click it in your eclipse and it will show you configurable area by which you can set midlet properties and icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NetBeans when you change/set MIDlet-Icon it will update the  `MIDlet-Icon` property of JAD.

In Eclipse either you change it manually or use [JAD editor](http://eclipseme.org/docs/jadeditor.html) for the same.

Comment: hi.I had tried to find JAD editor but i could not able to.Can you plz help me where i got JAD editor.So that i can edit it.Thanks you

Comment: At this point of time I have no eclipse setup for J2ME, Try checking that link you will get it just by playing around in few min.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the midlet tab in "Application Descriptor" pane in Eclipse.
You can set the midlet related options there.